# How do these two books compare?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, reference-request, soft-question, book-recommendation

I am interested in buying a physical copy of one of the following books:

1. *A Course of Pure Mathematics* by Hardy
2. *Differential and Integral Calculus* by Landau

I have superficially read the table of contents of Hardy's book. But I do not know the contents on Landau's text. I would like to see the table of contents of Landau's book, but I have not been able to find it. With that being said, if you have read any of the previous texts, what is your opinion on it/them? What are the pros and cons of each text?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't own that second book, but I found its table of contents [here](https://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/differential-and-integral-calculus).

Comment: Hardy's book is my favorite (a large part of my reputation points here are due to my understanding of calculus gained from this book). This book contains a lot of explanations in English rather than via math symbols.

Comment: Thank you all for the comments! I will be checking with detail the table of contents of each text, but as of now, I feel like buying Hardy's text